# Loading a cubemap from one texture

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to load a cubemap from single texture [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OmZm.png).
How can i specify texture region for each cubemap face (GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_*)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can project it into a cube and set the UVs but that way you will loose some of the features and its generally not recommended but its the simplest answer I can give

Comment: is it the only way? i also tried something like glTexSubImage2D but could not get it to work